# 中間テーブル同士を比較して取得するSQL文をかきたいです。(IN句かEXISTを用いるのかとは思いますが)

Tags: mysql, sql

ceremonies_categoriesとusers_category（どちらとも中間テーブル）のcategory_idを見比べて、
同じカテゴリを持っているceremony(式典)を取得するSQLをかきたいです。

・ceremonies_categories(式典が持つカテゴリ)
・users_category（利用ユーザーが選択するカテゴリ）

【目的】
利用ユーザーが興味を持つカテゴリを提示するためのSQL

【関係し得るテーブル】
・ceremony
・ceremonies_categories
・user
・category
・users_category

【考案例】

```
SELECT * from ceremonies WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_categories WHERE users_categories.user_id = 1)

SELECT * from ceremonies WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_categories WHERE users_categories.category_id in ceremonies_categories.category_id)
```

こういうSQLを考えましたが、よくわからなかったため質問しました。
（1つめのSQL文はエラーなくいきましたが、これが正しいのかどうかよくわからず）
（2つめのSQL文はEXISTの中で、IN句も使っており、アンチパターンな気がしまして。かといって解決策が思いつかず）

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

カラム名がわからないのと、手元にデータがないのであてずっぽうですが、
次のようなSQLになると思います。

例）ユーザID=1のユーザが、興味を持っているカテゴリの式典一覧

```
SELECT ceremonies.*
  FROM ceremonies, ceremonies_categories, users_categories
 WHERE ceremonies.id = ceremonies_categories.ceremonies_id
   AND ceremonies_categories.category_id = users_categories.category_id
   AND users_categories.user_id = 1
```

Comment: 私の説明が不足している点がいくつかありましのでいちど閉じさせて頂きます。ご回答頂き誠にありがとうございます。